# Multiple Android apps signed with same debug key can't use Firebase phone authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase project that has multiple Android apps with unique app IDs. Each app is a private labeled version. When testing, Android Studio signs each app with the same debug signing key. This causes only one app to properly authenticate while debugging. The Firebase web console only allows an SHA hash to be used once. Do I have to constantly move the debug signing key between apps in the Firebase console in order to test? Is there a better way?

Comment: Quick clarifications: "Android Studio signs each app with the same debug signing key" --> actually, the build tools inside your Android SDK are the ones responsible for that. They generate a single debug key that is used by all of your projects... And Firebase UI doesn't depend on SHA hash. Firebase Authentication is the one that does.

Comment: I clarified my question. By Firebase UI I meant the web console UI.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own debug keystore for each project, add a signing config for debug same as you would for release e.g.

```
    signingConfigs {
        ...
        debug {
            keyAlias 'mydebugkey'
            keyPassword 'mydebugpassword'
            storeFile file('mydebug.keystore')
            storePassword 'mydebugpassword'
        }
    }
```

keep it in the repo and every developer will sign their develop builds with the same keystore too which can be convenient for stuff that checks fingerprints. Should not be a security concern because the debug keystore should **only** be used for unpublished test builds.